# Does blowing bubbles at the front of a ship increase efficiencies?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Would this make an air envelope that the hull could smooth past with less friction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This technique is called [supercavitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercavitation). So far it has only been applied to objects no larger than, say, a torpedo, because it not easy to produce a stable bubble the size of a ship when moving at high velocities.